# Render value to tenths place in nunjucks template?

Tags: nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

Using the round() filter I can achieve the correct precision to the tenths place as in

```
{{ value | round(1) }}
```

however I still want to display the tenths place if `value` is zero or a whole integer. (0.0 instead of 0, 3.0 instead of 3)

**Is there a different method or other way to render *all* values to the tenths place?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic for the custom filter since the round filter will not maintain a tenths place for zero or whole integers:

```
nunjucks.configure().addFilter('tenths', function(num) {
        return parseFloat(num).toFixed(1);
    });
```

Then usage is the same as any filter:

```
{{ num | tenths }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add you own [filter](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#addfilter)

```
var env = nunjucks.configure(...

env.addFilter('round1', function(num) {
    if (!isNaN(num))
        return '???';

    return parseFloat(num).toFixed(1);    
});
```

Usage

```
{{ value | round1 }}
```

Comment: The above logic will return  '???' for everything because the if statement is not enclosed, and the logic is reversed for isNaN.

Comment: Yeah. It's a bug. `if (isNaN(num)) ...` is correct check, of course.